# Comprobar si una variable en un formulario es unica en 2 modelos simultaneos

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Veran, tengo un formulario para registrar a un nuevo usuario, el cual tiene entre sus variable el email.
Estas son las condiciones que debe cumplir:

> 'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users'

La condición `unique:user` impide que introduzca un valor que ya esta en la tabla de usuarios `User`, pero tambien tengo otra tabla llamada `Tabu`, en la cual introduzco los emails de usuarios baneados y eliminados de la primera tabla.
No se podra usar un email que aparezca en cualquiera de las 2 tablas. ¿Como lo logro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debería ser tan sencillo como utilizar dos veces la regla de validación:

```
'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users|unique:tabu'
```

Esto funcionaría si el nombre del campo es email en ambas tablas, de lo contrario habría que pasar el nombre de la columna que se debe comparar también.

Comment: Esta correcto. Y ahora que lo pienso, en messages(), con 'email.unique', hago que aparezca un mensaje de error, ¿pero es posible hacer que aparezca 2 posibles mensajes, según cual de las 2 tablas ya tiene ese email?

Comment: No es posible con lo que ofrece Laravel _out-of-the-box_, para ello sería necesario crear validadores personalizados.

Comment: Vale. En fin, con esto he solucionado la validación de varias tablas.